# XMLHttpRequest cannot load due to access control checks

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i'm getting a lot of errors in different browsers when opening a page that shows a youtube video.
i looked the topic and it turns out it is something about "Cros", i tried to follow the steps to get that enabled but with no luck,
here is what i have done in my startup.cs, i'm using .net core 5

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
   
        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {

        });


        services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
                           options.UseSqlServer(
                               Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
       ));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUserModel, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {


        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().
                        AllowAnyMethod().
                        AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.100"));
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
           endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
       name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });


    }
}
```

here is the errors i'm getting in safari.
[image]
any help is appreciated.

Comment: At first glance this looks like Safari is blocking content.

Comment: CORS won't be the issue here. Are you running an adblocker, or do you have a Content Security Policy (CSP)?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with your code.
you can't open youtube in your website unless you use embeded url.

1- click on share
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJJCK.png)

2- click on embed and copy the code
[see image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZgj5.png)